# Page Navigation Winui3 WinRT/C++

Tags: navigation, c++-winrt, winui-3, winui

I'm trying to navigate to pages through NavigationView in WinRT/C++ WinUI3. In navigating pages I found this as a way to navigate in SelectionChanged event or ItemInvoked event:

> this->ContentFram().Navigate(xaml_typename());

But when I run the app I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> *Error    C2338   static_assert failed:* '**T must be WinRT
> type.**'  ****\Users****Generated
> Files\winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h 657

I don't know how to add other pages and use them in

> MainWindow.cpp

as far as it seems different from C# Winui3 to me, I appreciate any suggestion in this matter.

Comment: You get this diagnostic when passing an *implementation type* into an interface expecting a *projected type* (see [What do the projected type and the implementation type mean?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#what-do-the-projected-type-and-the-implementation-type-mean-)). Make sure you understand that this is a compiler error, so you aren't actually running the application. The compiler output is probably more useful than Visual Studio's Error List tool window.

Comment: The above reply is correct. WinUI3 is also production ready. I wrote a commercial application using WinUI3 and C++/WinRT (you can find it on the Microsoft Store under the name BioNet). There I also included navigation. If you like I can send you the relevant parts of the source code.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use Frame()->Navigate(xaml_typename()); Why are you doing this . . . Frame() is the normal usage.

Comment: Alright. How can I reach you Hamed?